# Using unicode in a regular expression with PHP

Tags: php, regex, internationalization, expression, preg-match

I'm trying to add the character `Ö` (U+00D6) to my regular expression below. Apparently something is going wrong because it's not working on my `preg_match` function.

The regular expression that works fine:

```
/^([A-Z]{1})[a-z]{1,31}$/
```

The one that should work but does not:

```
/^([A-Z\x{00D6}]{1})[a-z]{1,31}$/
```

I'm obviously trying to create a regular expression that is started with an uppercase letter extended with `Ö` and followed by lowercase letters. In total, the length of the string must be between 2-32.  What is wrong with the regular expression that contains the Unicode expression for `Ö`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\x{00D6}` will only match the single byte `\xD6` symbol. When you pass in a string to [`preg_match`](http://php.net/preg_match) it's however most likely encoded in UTF-8, which is `\xC3 \x96`.

You need to use the [`/u` modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#~PCRE8) for your regex to support that.

```
/^([A-Z\x{00D6}]{1})[a-z]{1,31}$/u
```

Also the `{1}` is decorative, but redundant.

Comment: You just saved my day. Thank you for the answer to the actual question and the part about {1} being redundant.